# cannot use both TOMCAT server and my internet connection

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, localhost, ports

I cannot have my tomcat server started and at the same time use internet.

- either I can start Tomcat (in Eclipse) and internet is not available.
- or I can access the internet but tomcat cannot be started.

Here the original probleme I had when I first wanted to use Tomcat and display my html page on localhost.
**GRAVE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:** I find a way to start the Tomcat Server: in the terminal:

```
sudo lsof -i : 8005 # checks port 80
sudo route -n flush
sudo route add default 192.168.1.1
```

then I can use tomcat and localhost:8080 but my internet connexion is dead

if I want my internet connexion then I stop the tomcat server by clicking on the red square in eclipse and then in the terminal I do:

```
sudo route -n flush
sudo route add default 192.168.0.1
```

THen I can use internet but tomcat cannot be restarted. I have to undergo the first process.

this of course is a very boring process and I would like to know what 's wrong and how I could fix it.

I use tomcat 9 / Mac OS sierra / Eclipse Neon3

Comment: Why do you have to run the first commands?

Comment: This is not related to java programming in general. But: Why you need to add a new route to access your tomcat at localhost? Localhost is normally 127.0.0.1 and no new route is necessary. What happens if you do not set a new route after tomcat start?

Comment: Show us your route table in both cases. server fault might be a better place for this question.

Comment: the 3 sudo I use I find them on internet. I did not even knew what they performed when I use it at the first place. only know that solve the probleme of "FAILURE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]" and then I can start Tomcat but don't get any internet connexion (cannot reach google.com for instance)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "my internet connexion is dead", do you mean that your network connection drops or that your DNS lookups fail? (What do you think this command is doing and why are you performing it: sudo route add default 192.168.1.1?)

If your program is modifying your system's connectivity settings, I would strongly recommend against preventing it from doing that. There's no reason for it to do so at that level, a more appropriate place to set settings would be at some deploy stage.

Alternatively, you could run your app in a Docker container which I strongly suspect will solve your problem. Visit www.docker.com to learn more.

Comment: I perform "sudo route add default 192.168.1.1" because I found it on internet. Do know what this does exactly or why it solve the issue. Just know that then I can start tomcat but my internet connection doesn't work (cannot go to any website throw my current browser)